# how to get sum of cells in a excel row based on the status mention in each of the near by cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is the sample data set I have:
[image: Sample]

I am currently facing challenges in creating a formula in Excel to sum the values in odd-numbered columns based on the payment status in adjacent even-numbered columns.
My dataset starts at cell A3, where odd-numbered columns contain values, and even-numbered columns contain corresponding payment statuses.

I have attempted several formulas, including the use of `SUMPRODUCT`, but I am unable to achieve the desired result.

Here is the latest formula I've tried for "PAID" in cell T3:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(B3:S3)-COLUMN(B3), 2) = 0)*(B3:S3="PAID")*(A3:S3))
```

And for "NOTPAID" in cell U3:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(B3:S3)-COLUMN(B3), 2) = 0)*(B3:S3="NOTPAID")*(A3:S3))
```

Unfortunately, this formula is not producing the expected results. I suspect there might be an issue with the logic or the approach.

Could someone please provide guidance on creating a formula that correctly sums the values in odd-numbered columns based on the payment status in even-numbered columns?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue if what you share is a screenshot. Please share your sample in table format instead so people can copy it. That said and at first glance: I don't think you can have `N8:AH8` along with `M8:AH8` in the same `SUMPRODUCT`. The number of cells do not match if you do so. You may want to change the former in  `N8:AI8` or the latter in `M8:AG8`.

Comment: Try `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(B3:R3*(C3:S3="PAID"),)`.

Comment: Why check for even columns if only those columns mention `PAID`. Why wouldn't `SUMPRODUCT ((B3:S3="PAID")*(A3:S3))` work?

Answer (score 0):

The formula main problem when you multiply a string with a boolean which is a value error. To resolve this use `IFERROR` sg. like this.

`=SUM(IFERROR((B3:S3="paid")*A3:S3,0))`

this also resolve the pair-impair column problem.

Sidenote: T column is your data last column. Therefore seems you need in U3 and V3

`=SUM(IFERROR((B3:T3="paid")*A3:S3,0))`

`=SUM(IFERROR((B3:T3="notpaid")*A3:S3,0))`

Answer (score 0):

### Sum Adjacent to Matches

[image]

```
=LET(data,$B3:$S12,match_data,"PAID",
BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,SUM(FILTER(r,HSTACK(
    DROP(IFNA(XMATCH(r,match_data),),,1),0),0)))))
```

Note that `match_data` could be `T2` or `U2` or `T2:U2` or `{"PAID";"NOT"}` ... etc.

**Edit: Another (Single Filter) Idea**

```
=LET(data,B3:S12,group_cols,2,sum_col,1,filter_col,2,filter_string,"PAID",
    zs,group_cols*(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)/group_cols)-1),
    t,CHOOSECOLS(data,zs+sum_col)*(CHOOSECOLS(data,zs+filter_col)=filter_string),
BYROW(t,LAMBDA(r,SUM(r))))
```

**4 Columns, Single Filter**

```
=LET(data,B3:Q12,group_cols,4,sum_col,1,filter_col,4,filter_string,{"PAID"},
    zs,group_cols*(SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)/group_cols)-1),
    t,CHOOSECOLS(data,zs+sum_col)*(CHOOSECOLS(data,zs+filter_col)=filter_string),
BYROW(t,LAMBDA(r,SUM(r))))
```

[image]